# How do I implement NodeJS "Did you mean" feature?

Tags: node.js

How can I implement a "Did you mean" feature in NodeJS? I searched the internet and found a tutorial that uses a webserver but I will be using this for a Discord bot, so I can't really use tutorials that involve web servers, etc.

For example:

```
User enters command: restrat
Actual command: restart
Bot Message: Command not found, did you mean "restart"?
```

Is this possible using NodeJS? If so, may I know how I  can implement this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials on the 'toobz about building discord bots with nodejs. nodejs makes it fairly easy to build a web server, but is useful for building all sorts of protocol handlers. If you deploy this on Heroku, you want a Worker Dyno, not a Web Dyno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether in NodeJS or the browser, some code is needed to find a command that most closely resembles the text entered by the user.

This code uses the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) calculation to return the closest match.

```js
const jsLevenshtein = require("js-levenshtein");

function closestCommand (userText, commands) {
  let minDistance = Infinity;
  return commands.reduce((closest, cmd) => {
    const cmdDistance = jsLevenshtein(userText, cmd);
    if (cmdDistance < minDistance) {
      minDistance = cmdDistance;
      return cmd;
    }
    return closest;
  }, '');
}

const myCommands = ['quit', 'login', 'logout', 'restart', 'refresh'];
const userCommand = 'restrat';

console.log(`closest command is '${closestCommand(userCommand, myCommands)}'`);
// closest command is 'restart'
```

[Working code in RunKit.](https://runkit.com/terrymorse58/runkit-npm-js-levenshtein)

It should be straightforward to add this to a NodeJS app.